# Adding components to BorderLayout

Tags: border-layout

I'm trying to implement BorderLayout within IntelliJ and am having trouble getting it to work. It compiles fine, but when it runs I see the viewer for a second and then it crashes. The code I currently have is

```
    Button Next=new Button("Next");
    Button Back=new Button("Back");
    Container panel1=new Container();
    Container panel2=new Container();
    home = new Form("Home");
    home.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    home.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST,panel1);
    home.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST,panel2);
    panel1.addComponent(Next);
    panel2.addComponent(Back);
```

The error I get after it crashes is "Cannot add component to BorderLayout Container without constraint parameter". I tried researching a constraint parameter and also working with BorderLayout in IntelliJ, but any texts I found were either not helpful or too complicated to understand. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that if you want to add a component to a border layout you have to specify where to put it. You've done this when adding components to home, but you haven't when you add components to `panel1` and `panel2`. You need to add `BorderLayout.EAST` (or `WEST`, or whatever) to get:

```
panel1.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, Next);
panel2.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, Back);
```

However, I think you're using this wrong. You probably don't want a border layout in panel1 or panel2 -- they're fine with the default flow layout, so if you remove the `panel1/2.setLayout()` lines your code should work fine.

BTW: In java we don't use capital letters at the start of variables, so `Next` and `Back` should be `next` and `back`. Also, `panel1` should be something like `nextPanel`, and `panel2` should be something like `backPanel`.

To add one more thing -- nobody uses awt any more. We've all moved on (mostly to html5). So, trying this in swing, you would get:

```
import javax.swing.*;
...
JButton next = new JButton("Next");
JButton back = new JButton("Back");
JFrame home = new JFrame("Home");
home.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
home.add(back, BorderLayout.WEST);
home.add(next, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested but I'm still running into the same problem. My new code is

Comment: Button Next=new Button("Next");
        Button Back=new Button("Back");
        Container panel1=new Container();
        Container panel2=new Container();

        //create and build the home Form
        home = new Form("Home");
        home.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        home.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST,panel1);
        home.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST,panel2);
        panel1.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, Next);
        panel2.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, Back);

Comment: I've added some more sample code to my answer for you